# MSSQL Como descobrir qual tabela um registro foi incluido ou modificado

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, microsoft

Existe meio de descobrir via consulta qual tabela em um banco de dados sofreu alteração de Update ou Insert?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Explique o problema pra podermos propor uma solução.

Comment: Existe os Triggers (Gatilhos)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que conferi nos foruns de SQL SERVE, esta consulta retornará o valor do ultimo insert:

```
SELECT o.name as ObjectName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
join sepm01.sys.objects o on s.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'sepm01')
```

Além disso encontrei um componente que vai te dar u mtrack mais preciso sobre isso:
[SQL Server - Change Tracking](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/537649/SQL-Server-Change-Tracking-CT)